# call luatex from a lua program

Tags: pdf, lua, typesetting

I want my `lua` program to support PDF output that contains typeset equations.

I know you can call `lua` from `luatex`, but is it possible to call `luatex` as a library call from `lua`?

If that is not possible, then where should I start looking, `luaHPDF`?

`edit:`A rough idea, but something like this--load luatex (somehow) and use its functions natively:

```
require luatex
local g1 = luatex.node.new("glyph")
g1.font = luatex.font.current()
g1.lang = luatex.tex.language
g1.char = 86

local head,tail,success = luatex.node.kerning(g1)
local hbox = luatex.node.hpack(head)
local vbox = luatex.node.vpack(hbox)

luatex.node.write(vbox)
```

Comment: Do you need a lua module or is executing a "binary" good enough? Could you not just execute `luatex` directly?

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but I don't want to shell out, I'd like to call the luatex commands as if it was a library.

Comment: What commands exactly? What would you want your usage to look like?